# run windows command from oracle database trigger

Tags: windows, oracle11g, command

i have oracle database (11g) trigger run after inserting on table, i need to run external program by this trigger through windows command like this:

```
c:\my_external_apps\app1.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

i am trying this code but it doesn't work:

```
create or replace TRIGGER GE_MAIN_NOTIFICATION_SEND AFTER INSERT ON TABLE 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_program(program_name => 'UPLOADNC', program_type => 'EXECUTABLE', 
program_action => 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.exe /C c:\my_external_apps\app1.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 ', 
enabled => TRUE); 
END;
```

and this is the error

```
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DURRA.GE_MAIN_NOTIFICATION_SEND'
27486. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a scheduler operation without the
       required privileges.
*Action:   Ask a sufficiently privileged user to perform the requested
       operation, or grant the required privileges to the proper user(s).
```

how i can do that?? i am beginner with oracle database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you haven't been granted the privileges necessary to call `dbms_scheduler.create_program`.  I expect that you are missing the `create job` privilege.

However, if you resolve that problem, your next problem will be that `dbms_scheduler.create_program` does an implicit commit and commits are not allowed inside triggers.  That means that you cannot call `dbms_scheduler.create_program` from a trigger (unless you made the trigger an autonomous transaction which would create a separate set of issues).  The right way to solve the problem would almost certainly be to use the older `dbms_job` package.  Since that package doesn't implicitly commit, you can submit a job as part of a larger transaction.

Of course, if you're using the `dbms_job` package to do your job scheduling, you lose out on the ability of `dbms_scheduler` to call out to the operating system.  Instead, you'd need to do something like creating a [Java stored procedure that calls out to the operating system](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241).  There are multiple examples of this on the web, I linked to one from Tom Kyte.

So, at a high level, your trigger would call `dbms_job.submit` to submit the job.  The job would then call your Java stored procedure.  Your Java stored procedure would make the actual call out to the operating system of the database server.